# Apply style (filter) when route active

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a few elements in my navbar that have a color defined, which I am changing by creating a filter in my typescript code. But I want to change this color dynamically.

I have a string that contains a value 'greyscale(73%) saturate(1400%)'. How do I get that string to the fa-icon's filter property in the css?

```html
<div>
    <button class="button button-clear" style="margin: 5px;" routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLink]="[buttonData.route]" [ngbTooltip]="buttonData.route">
        <fa-icon [icon]="buttonData.icon" class="fa-2x p-3"></fa-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

```css
.active {
  border: white 3px;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  fa-icon {
    filter: invert(100%) brightness(50%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%);
  }
}
```

```js
export class NavbarButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  filter: string;
  @Input() buttonData: NavbarButtonData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filter = hexToCSS(this.buttonData.highlightColor).filter;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom a font-awesome icon you have to change the `-webkit-background-clip` and the `-webkit-text-fill-color`.

So in your your situation you can do something like :

```
.my-icon {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9c47fc,#d2354b); // choice your color gradient here 
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if the icons are not from font-awesome that won't anymore will it? Not all my icons are from that package. some (not available there) are my own icons. I also want to be able to apply this on images and other elements, hence the reason I am doing it the way I do it.

Comment: Yes you can change all icons :) But I suggest you for your own icon to change the color before uploaded it on your project, it will be faster